# Caret package - cross-validating GAM with both smooth and linear predictors

Tags: r, r-caret, cross-validation, gam, mgcv

I would like to cross validate a GAM model using caret. My GAM model has a binary outcome variable, an isotropic smooth of latitude and longitude coordinate pairs, and then linear predictors. Typical syntax when using mgcv is:

```
gam1 <- gam( y ~ s(lat , long) + x1 + x2, family = binomial(logit) )
```

I'm not quite sure how to specify this model using the train function in caret. This is my syntax more or less:

```
cv <- train(y ~ lat + long + x1 + x2, 
            data = data, 
            method = "gam", 
            family = "binomial", 
            trControl = trainControl(method = "LOOCV", number=1, repeats=), 
            tuneGrid = data.frame(method = "GCV.Cp", select = FALSE))
```

The problem is that I only want lat and long to be smoothed and x1 and x2 to be treated as linear.

Thanks!

Comment: Agree with @李哲源ZheyuanLi  but doesn't `caret::train` accept regression or smoothing spline functions in its formula argument?

Comment: I'm not seeing any difficulties in using splines or polynomial functions in the formula argument to `train` when `method="glm"`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is very interesting to see someone using `mgcv` outside `mgcv`. After a bit of research, I am here to frustrate you: using `mgcv` with `caret` is a bad idea, at least with current support from `caret`.

Let's me just ask you a few fundamental questions, if you are using `caret`:

1. How can you specify the number of knots, as well as spline basis class for a smooth function?
2. How can you specify 2D smooth function?
3. How can you specify tensor product spline with `te` or `ti`?
4. How can you tweak with smoothing parameters?

If you want to know what `caret::train` is doing with `method = "gam"`, check out its fitting routine:

```
getModelInfo(model = "gam", regex = FALSE)$gam$fit

function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...) { 
            dat <- if(is.data.frame(x)) x else as.data.frame(x)
            modForm <- caret:::smootherFormula(x)
            if(is.factor(y)) {
              dat$.outcome <- ifelse(y == lev[1], 0, 1)
              dist <- binomial()
            } else {
              dat$.outcome <- y
              dist <- gaussian()
            }
            modelArgs <- list(formula = modForm,
                              data = dat,
                              select = param$select, 
                              method = as.character(param$method))
            ## Intercept family if passed in
            theDots <- list(...)
            if(!any(names(theDots) == "family")) modelArgs$family <- dist
            modelArgs <- c(modelArgs, theDots)                 
            out <- do.call(getFromNamespace("gam", "mgcv"), modelArgs)
            out    
            }
```

You see the `modForm <- caret:::smootherFormula(x)` line? That line is the key, while other lines is just routine construction of a model call. So, let's have a check with what GAM formula `caret` is constructing:

```
caret:::smootherFormula

function (data, smoother = "s", cut = 10, df = 0, span = 0.5, 
    degree = 1, y = ".outcome") 
{
    nzv <- nearZeroVar(data)
    if (length(nzv) > 0) 
        data <- data[, -nzv, drop = FALSE]
    numValues <- sort(apply(data, 2, function(x) length(unique(x))))
    prefix <- rep("", ncol(data))
    suffix <- rep("", ncol(data))
    prefix[numValues > cut] <- paste(smoother, "(", sep = "")
    if (smoother == "s") {
        suffix[numValues > cut] <- if (df == 0) 
            ")"
        else paste(", df=", df, ")", sep = "")
    }
    if (smoother == "lo") {
        suffix[numValues > cut] <- paste(", span=", span, ",degree=", 
            degree, ")", sep = "")
    }
    if (smoother == "rcs") {
        suffix[numValues > cut] <- ")"
    }
    rhs <- paste(prefix, names(numValues), suffix, sep = "")
    rhs <- paste(rhs, collapse = "+")
    form <- as.formula(paste(y, rhs, sep = "~"))
    form
}
```

In short, it creates additive, univariate smooth. This is the classic form when GAM was first proposed.

To this end, you lose a significant amount of control on `mgcv`, as listed previously.

To verify this, let me construct a similar example to your case:

```
set.seed(0)
dat <- gamSim(eg = 2, scale = 0.2)$data[1:3]
dat$a <- runif(400)
dat$b <- runif(400)
dat$y <- with(dat, y + 0.3 * a - 0.7 * b)

#            y         x         z          a         b
#1 -0.30258559 0.8966972 0.1478457 0.07721866 0.3871130
#2 -0.59518832 0.2655087 0.6588776 0.13853856 0.8718050
#3 -0.06978648 0.3721239 0.1850700 0.04752457 0.9671970
#4 -0.17002059 0.5728534 0.9543781 0.03391887 0.8669163
#5  0.55452069 0.9082078 0.8978485 0.91608902 0.4377153
#6 -0.17763650 0.2016819 0.9436971 0.84020039 0.1919378
```

So we aim to fit a model: `y ~ s(x, z) + a + b`. The data `y` is Gaussian, but this does not matter; it does not affect how `caret` works with `mgcv`.

```
cv <- train(y ~ x + z + a + b, data = dat, method = "gam", family = "gaussian",
            trControl = trainControl(method = "LOOCV", number=1, repeats=1), 
            tuneGrid = data.frame(method = "GCV.Cp", select = FALSE))
```

You can extract the final model:

```
fit <- cv[[11]]
```

So what formula is it using?

```
fit$formula
#.outcome ~ s(x) + s(z) + s(a) + s(b)
```

See? Apart from being "additive, univariate", it also leaves everything of `mgcv::s` to its default: default `bs = "tp"`, default `k = 10`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, all good points. Yes if what I wanted is to compare adaptive to tp to te smooths I don't see how to do it in caret. So I suppose there must be a way to hard code a cross validation, but that's beyond my skills. Can anyone point to some code where I can do it?

Thanks